# Why does multicollinearity happen when I convert the variables into categorical variables?

Tags: r, multicollinearity

I'm trying to analyze the data with conditional logit model.

When I converted the integer variables into categorical variables, some of the results are omitted because of the collinearity.

Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem? I tried to find the correlation between the variables, but it seems all variables have the correlation. I got lost from here :/

The below coding are just the examples:

```
data2$Introduction <- as.factor(data2$Introduction)
clogout2 <- clogit(RES~Introduction+Waterside+Play+Wetland+WTP+strata(STR), data=data2)
```

sample result:

```
Waterside3           NA        NA  0.000000      NA       NA
```

I tried to find the vif:
but all variables are saying: there are aliased coefficients in the model.

Also, tried to see the chi-square, it also showed the significant p-value among all variables.

I also tried to convert the variables into categorical without dummy variables("0", "1"). But couldn't find the correct coding so far...

Comment: For me, it is hard to imagine how your data looks like and why it is doing this thing. Could you try to reproduce this erroneous behaviour with some example data set in R, and update your question? Alternatively, you can add the `dput()` a minimal version of your data set to your question. This makes communication much easier and lets us understand what is going on by executing code on our own machines. read more: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example